# Exibir alerta feito em html e css por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom Dia, 
Estou criando um form em html e javascript para validação, minha ideia é criar um alerta de sucesso ou falha com html e css(bonitinho e etc), mas não sei como posso "chamar" dar um require nesse alerta que eu criei, alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1" action="">
Nome: <input type="text" name="name" value="Nome"><br>
Sobrenome: <input type="text" name="sname" value="Sobrenome"><br><br>
</form> 
<button onclick="takeValue()">mostra valor</button>

<p id="teste"></p>

<script>
function takeValue() {
var x = document.getElementById("form1");
var texto = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    texto += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML = texto;
if(texto == "Nome<br>Sobrenome<br>"){
alert("quero exibir alerta de SUCESSO feito com html e css");
}
else{
    alert("quero exibir alerta de ERRO feito com html e csss");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Você pode usar jQuery?

Comment: tu tem um exemplo de código para que eu possa entender a ideia?

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) é uma biblioteca javascript que já tem muita coisa pronta. No caso, para fazer um modal/dialog, como você deseja, basta usar jQuery-UI e customizar a caixa como você desejar... Por isso perguntei se você pode utilizar jQuery.

Comment: Explique a forma que você deseja mostrar essa mensagem. Se é por um texto na página, por um dialog modal, um alert, etc.

Comment: queria que meu alerta desse 'display' na div onde está sendo preenchido o formulário, para avisar se falta algo etc.. aqueles bem genérico que vemos na maioria dos formularios

Comment: Ah, vc pode criar duas divs, uma para a mensagem de erro e outra para a mensagem de sucesso.. dai ambas deixa com "display:none". Depois é só usar um style.display = 'block' na div desejada.

Answer (score 3):

A funcionalidade que procuras é a de um modal/dialog.

Encontras isso no jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/, ou noutras bibliotecas.

Basicamente é uma `div` que podes customizar com HTML e CSS que mostras só quando necessário. Muitas vezes coloca-se também uma outra div, por baixo, a servir como *overlay* para impedir cliques na página senão na janela do alert(dialog/modal).

Sugiro usares um já feito como o do jQuery. Uma ideia simples em JavaScript/CSS nativo seria:

```
document.getElementById('dialogContent').innerHTML = infoText;
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
```

para mostrar o dialog.

```
function fechar() {
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

para fechar.

CSS (sugestão rápida):

```
#overlay {
    display:none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9000;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#dialog {
    background-color: #ddf;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 9001;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#fechar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/of3paudy/6/

Comment: Não era bem oque eu queria, mas me ajudou bastante no conceito da ideia, obrigado!

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas explica melhor o que querias? viste o link que sugeri (com jQuery)? -> http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: esse lance de incluir todas as divs na pagina e aplicar o display com javascript para ativar pela demanda, teoricamente obriga o usuário a carregar tudo sem ainda ter solicitado ou estou errado?

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas tem de carregar 2 divs vazias. Isso é irrelevante em termos de performance. O conteudo adicionas depois, antes de mostrar.

Comment: olhei o site, é bastante coisa, incrivelmente uteis, olha por favor esse link, imagina que eu fosse utilizar esses alertas http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/new-style-alerts, seria muitas divs para fazer esse swap de divs para  efetuar o alerta, realmente não afeta a performace?

Comment: na verdade eu sinto que não seria a forma mais correta de o faze-lo

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas esse link é o mesmo que a minha resposta só que com CSS do Boostrap. Acho que conheces pouca coisa, sugiro usares o dialog do jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algo assim, mas não me pareceu muito 'correto', até porque a div ocupava o espaço.

```
   function display()
   {
   var elem = document.getElementById("teste");

   if(elem.style.visibility == "hidden"){
    elem.style.visibility="";

   } else {
    elem.style.visibility="hidden";
   }

   }
```